# Boxplot in R. Adding steps to y axis

Tags: r, boxplot

I am new to R programming and I am trying to create a simple boxplot diagram, but the result is not actually the desired.

My data are like the following style (the total prices are around 1k).

```
Quarter DFT
1st 1,61
1st 2,35
1st 1,74
2nd 2,56
2nd 1,79
2nd 1,84
2nd 1,69
3rd 1,85
3rd 1,73
3rd 2,62
3rd 2,43
3rd 1,85
```

What I am looking for:

[image: What I am looking for]

What I get:

[image: What I get]

The code that I am using:

```
DFTvalues<-read.table(file.choose(),header = T)
p<- ggplot(data=DFTvalues, aes(x=Quarter, y=DFT))
q<- p+  geom_jitter(aes(color=Quarter))+geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7, outlier.color=NA)
q
```

Actually I need to put a step o DFT values on the y axis and appear the box that supposed to be there with the mean.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe try `read.table(file.choose(),header = T, dec=",")` because I assume that's supposed to be a numeric column of values. R normally expects to see `.` and not `,` in numbers unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Perfect!! That was the solution!!! Thank you!!!
http://prntscr.com/hztsbi